# Go fails to infer type in assignment: "non-name on left side of :="

Tags: go, type-inference

This snippet works as expected [play.golang.org/p/VuCl-OKMav](http://play.golang.org/p/VuCl-OKMav)

```go
i := 10
next := 11
prev, i := i, next
```

However this nearly identical snippet gives `non-name f.Bar on left side of :=` [play.golang.org/p/J8NNWPugQG](http://play.golang.org/p/J8NNWPugQG)

```go
type Foo struct {
    Bar int
}

f := Foo{10}
next := 11
prev, f.Bar := f.Bar, next
```

What's special about the struct that stops type inference? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 26):

It's an <strike>open</strike> issue.

[Issue 6842](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6842): spec: Assigning to fields with short declaration notation

Comment: apparently, this is an impossibly hard problem ;) https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30318

Answer (score 22):

It's not really a type inference issue, it's just that the left-hand-side of `:=` must be a list of identifiers, and `f.Bar` is not an identifier, so it can't be declared — not even with `:=`'s slightly-more-permissive rules for what it can declare. See ["Short variable declarations" in *The Go Programming Language Specification*](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).

Comment: A related question: Is there a reason to not extend the short variable declaration's spec to allow any assignable name as well?

Comment: @deft_code: I don't know. I suspect that it would complicate the parser somewhat, since if arbitrarily complex expressions (with function calls and pointer dereferences and so on) can appear on the left-hand-side (long before the parser sees `:=`), then the parser has to provisionally allow undeclared identifiers in more complex contexts (until it either sees `:=` or can rule out that it's parsing a short variable declaration). But I don't know whether that was the reason. Maybe the language designers just felt that `prev, i := i, next` was as big an exception as they were willing to make.

Answer (score 14):

From the spec's [Short variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) section:

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may
>   redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in
>   the same block...with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank
>   variables is new.

So if you declare the variable inside another type (struct Foo in the example), it is disqualified by "provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block".

So the answer is to just set the pre-declared variable equal *not using the := syntax* to the value:

```
...
var prev int
prev, f.Bar = f.Bar, next
...
```

Answer (score 0):

it is just that you already assigned f to Foo
f := Foo{100}
in this case f.Bar is 100
so to reassign it just remove the column

```
var prev string
f := Foo{10}
next := 11
prev, f.Bar = f.Bar, next
this will work
```