# Go expected identifier on left side of :=syntax

Tags: go

Hello I am trying to make a connection to postgres using go, but I have the following error:

on this line :

> conn.pool, err := sql.Open("postgres", uri)

err:

> expected identifier on left side of :=syntax

I'm new to go and I don't know why and how to resolve this error, if someone can help me where I'm going wrong.

```
package database

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

type Db struct {
    pool *sql.DB
}

type Connection interface {
    Close()
    DB() *sql.DB
}

func NewPostgreSQLsql() (Connection, error) {
    var conn Db
    
    uri := getURI()

    conn.pool, err := sql.Open("postgres", uri)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := conn.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
        return nil, err
    }

    return &conn, nil
}

func (c *db) DB() *sql.DB {
    return c.pool
}

func (c *Db) Close() {
    c.pool.Close()
}

func getURI() string {
    dbPort, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("DB_PORT"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error on load db port from env:", err.Error())
        dbPort = 5432
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf(os.Getenv("DB_HOST"),
        dbPort,
        os.Getenv("DB_USER"),
        os.Getenv("DB_NAME"),
        os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"))
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/21345274/13860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot directly initialize and assign to `conn.pool` with `:=`

and you should initialize conn object

Try this

```
conn := Db{}
    
uri := getURI()

pool, err := sql.Open("postgres", uri)

conn.pool = pool
```

or

```
uri := getURI()

pool, err := sql.Open("postgres", uri)

conn := Db{pool}
```