# Golang: expected identifier on left side of :=syntax

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang and while trying to implement a simple client server model, I'm getting this error expected identifier on left side of :=syntax on line:

```
kvs.listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":9999")
```

Specifically the error is under kvs.

I'm not sure why this is happening. If I replace kvs.listener with a simple ln (i.e. no struct) the error go away. Can someone please help me in fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `=` when assigning to an existing variable, e.g. a struct field.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69102100/getting-error-non-name-on-left-side-of/69104323#69104323 / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345274/go-fails-to-infer-type-in-assignment-non-name-on-left-side-of

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`:=` is a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations). As its name says, it is to declare variables.

`kvs.listener` is not an identifier of a new variable you wish to declare, it's likely a field of an existing variable (or a variable of some package).

When you don't want a new variable, use simple [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments):

```
kvs.listener, err = net.Listen("tcp", ":9999")
```

If the `err` variable does not yet exist, you have to declare it prior:

```
var err error
kvs.listener, err = net.Listen("tcp", ":9999")
```

Comment: I am curious to understand why this is only necessary when one of the LHS variables is a struct type.  Usually := declares *any* previously undeclared symbols on the LHS, which may be either or both in cases like this (but must be at least one).    Why does the use of a struct variable then require that *both* variables be pre-declared?  This is super annoying.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like

```
 newVar, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":9999")
 kvs.listener = newVar
```

where newVar is a variable that you not used in the program